# Highlighting ascii tables

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

Some (ascii) reports I produce contain ascii tables, like this one:

```
+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
+======+======+======+
| bla  | bla  | bla  |
| bla  | bla  | bla  |
| bla  | bla  | bla  |
+------+------+------+
```

I am trying to find a way to highlight such tables using a vim syntax file. A simple highlighting should suffice - no need to distinguish between the `|`, the `=`, the `+` and the `-`. However, I do not want to highlight the words inside the table (only the skeleton), and I do not want to highlight `-`, `=` signs (etc.) outside of the table.

The problem with vim syntax files is that they have no way of determining what's "up" or "down" relatively to a given point. I would be OK with just highlighting per-line, for examples, lines like this:

```
+------+------+------+
```

even if they not create nice tables, but the problem is with lines like this:

```
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
```

which may be mixed with non-tabular code, like this Python code:

```
x = y\
    | z | u | v # | is here for 'or'
```

Can you think of a more elegant way of doing so? I've seen ome highlighters (other than vim) which highlight tables quite well...

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with *containmaint*, cp. `:help :syn contains`. First, define a region that spans the entire range of lines that the table is comprised of. I'm using a simplistic pattern for the header / footer line here, and assert that there's no `|` immediately above / below (in the neighboring line); refine this as needed:

```
syn region tableRegion start="|\@<!\n+[-+]*+$" end="^+[-+]*+\n|\@!" contains=tableRow
```

Then, define the (again, simplistic here) pattern to match the table rows, and mark this `contained`, so it will only match inside other syntax regions that `contains=` it.

```
syn match tableRow "^|.*|$" contained
```